# How can I open .cpp file in visual studio and make it display string literals with Cyrillic characters correctly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to open source file with C++ code from another person. While writing the code he used older version of visual studio then I have right now.
Cyrillic letters are distorted.

Stupidly confusing part of it is encoding problem. When I open .cpp file with any program, that can read text except for notepad++ English characters are displayed perfectly, but Cyrillic are distorted. Notepad++ shows that it opens that file in ANSI encoding. If I copy that correctly displayed text from notepad++ to other program (visual studio, standard windows notepad, google translator in browser, some online encoding converter) it becomes distorted again as if it was copying bytes instead of characters (this one blows my mind most of all).
Since .cpp file is basically just text file, I don't understand why can't I read it. And if it was damaged file - notepad++ wouldn't read it. Or at least it would show some error message, wouldn't it?

Here is how visual studio displays it:

```
cout << "����� ����� � ������� 100-999";
cout << "\n�������� 2 (��i� ����� �� � �� ������� �����) = " << d;
cout << "\n�������� 3 (��i� ����� �� �� �� ��������� ����) = " << f << "\n";
```

Here is correct code:

```
cout << "серед чисел в діапазоні 100-999";
cout << "\nзавдання 2 (усіх чисел де є дві однакові цифри) = " << d;
cout << "\nзавдання 3 (усіх чисел де не має однакових цифр) = " << f << "\n";
```

P.S. I know that questions about encoding were asked already billion times, but I didn't find proper answer, so please don't hit me too hard if it was answered before. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seeing it correctly depends on the encoding settings in your text editor. Remember, text files have no way of communicating their encoding. The editor must detect automatically or have some kind of setting or override to work properly.

Comment: if it loads as ANSI it would have to have the correct code page to show kyrillic, I guess. In VS, my best bet would be to try open it with UTF8 encoding. If you press CTRL-O you can chose in the open file dialog, which encoding to assume.

Comment: Should be encoding. The question is which encoding original file was on. Once you figure it out, you can either use this encoding in the editor, or, better yet, convert it to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a working solution for your problem which works fine in my Visual Studio 2017 and [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) with UTF-8 encoding output.

First of all use [u8 literal strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) which gives you UTF-8 output:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double d = 0.0;
    double f = 1.0;
    std::cout << u8"серед чисел в діапазоні 100-999";
    std::cout << u8"\nзавдання 2 (усіх чисел де є дві однакові цифри) = " << d;
    std::cout << u8"\nзавдання 3 (усіх чисел де не має однакових цифр) = " << f << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Then compile and run your program under [ConEmu console emulator](https://conemu.github.io/) which supports UTF-8 output. Accordling to [ConEmu Unicode support documentation](https://conemu.github.io/en/UnicodeSupport.html) you need to switch to UTF-8 with command `chcp 65001`:

```
chcp 65001
test.exe
```

It gives me the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was using different approach in that situation before. For instance `wcout << L"any text";` helps as well (just needs `setconsole` function first and probably `SetConsoleCP` and `SetConsoleOutputCP`). But the problem is not about console output. The problem is that this text is not shown in code. Those `�` signs is what visual studio shows in the source code. It's not in console. And of course when program tries to print `�` in console it can't convert it to something worthy...

Answer (score 1):

Save the file in Unicode encoding, preferably UTF8. Go to File menu and click Save As

[image]

When you click "Save with Encoding...", Visual Studio should give at least two UTF8 options:

"UTF8 with signature" 
"UTF8 without signature"

Microsoft products prefer UTF8 with signature (BOM), whereas Notepad++ prefer UTF8 without signature.